# How to extract type of specific key from interface

Tags: typescript

Given an interface like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: Some | Pretty | Complex | Type;
  age: number;
}
```

I'd like to get the type of a specific key, e.g. `name`. So I could e.g. write a function like (this code doesn't work):

```
function formatName(name: Person.name) {}
```

I know I could simply:

- duplicate the type
- extract the type of a key to a separate named type which I could reference in both places.

But I think there should be a way to accomplish this without duplication or introducing additional type names.

Comment: change it to `Person["name"]`

Comment: Thanks, I thought it must be something quite obvious.